# Birt: Charts and images not being displayed on Birtviewer

Tags: tomcat7, birt

I have deployed birtviewer on tomcat7/jre7 and have put a Birt report inside them. This dashboard is working fine on dev server but on prod server, when I access the dashbaords, the embedded images are not being displayed and the charts are showing a message that a plugin is needed t display the content. I can view the same dashboard fine on dev server.

[image]

Can someone please tell me what can be missing from tomcat to render this report correctly

Arif

Comment: do you use birtviewer on def server too or just birt designer?

Comment: its birtviewer on both dev and prod server. I have developed reports on my laptop designer, tested it on birtviewer/tomcat on my own laptop and it worked fine...then installed tomcat/birtviewer on customer's dev/QA server and deployed reports there..it worked fine. I don't have access to prod server to so I asked another guy to install tomcat/birtviewer there and I copied the whole Birtviewer folder from dev to prod. Technically its 100% same Birtviewer and dashboards thats on dev server

Comment: I have simply copied the birtviewer folder form tomcat/webapps on dev server to tomcat/webapps on prod server. the reports runs ok but neither any image nor any chart is being displayed.

Answer (score 1):

I assume those charts are in SVG format. Your prod server is  probably not setup to serve svg. Check if the relevant mapping exists in *[Tomcat home]/conf/web.xml*

```
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>svg</extension>
    <mime-type>image/svg+xml</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
```

Comment: Yes, you are correct. The output format is svg. Secondly, I have used some embedded images...they are jpg types..they are also not showing up..is it also because of this?

Comment: I have checked the web.xml and this actually exists in the file..<mime-mapping>
        <extension>svg</extension>
        <mime-type>image/svg+xml</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>svgz</extension>
        <mime-type>image/svg+xml</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>

   <mime-mapping>
        <extension>jpg</extension>
        <mime-type>image/jpeg</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>jpgm</extension>
        <mime-type>video/jpm</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>

Comment: still the jpg and svg both outputs are not displaying